# Determining which points cannot lie on a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle passes through the points $(3,4)$ and $(5,7)$. Which of the following points CANNOT lie of circle?

A) $(-2,-1)$

B) $(3,2)$

C) $(5,5)$

D) $(6,4)$

E) $(-1,-2)$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: is any condition else given?

Answer (score 3):

Any $3$ non collinear points can form a triangle, and thus all the $3$ points will lie on the circumcircle of the triangle. Thus the required condition so that they do not lie on the circle is that they lie on the same line which is satisfied by $(-1,-2)$

Comment: in the limit a line is a circle with infinite radius

Comment: @gimusi yes it is, but here I assume that is not considered as a circle

Comment: yes of course it is just a notation, good answer

Comment: @gimusi Thanks!